# Sequlize gives un Wanted info

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js, relational-database

i have two tables `Products` and `carts` and they are many to many relationship across `products_carts` table
i am getting specific cart and i am including `Product` with it so i can get the cart and their products
why i am getting `products_carts` with the products

my sequlize command:

```
const a = await Cart.findByPk(1,{
  attributes: ['id'],
  include: {
    model: Product,
    attributes: ['id'],
  },
});
```

the sql statement :

```
Executing (default): SELECT `cart`.`id`, `products`.`id` AS `products.id`,
`products->products_carts`.`createdAt` AS `products.products_carts.createdAt`, 
`products->products_carts`.`updatedAt` AS `products.products_carts.updatedAt`, 
`products->products_carts`.`cartId` AS `products.products_carts.cartId`, `products- 
>products_carts`.`productId` AS `products.products_carts.productId` FROM `carts` AS 
`cart` LEFT OUTER JOIN ( `products_carts` AS `products->products_carts` INNER JOIN 
`products` AS `products` ON `products`.`id` = `products->products_carts`.`productId`) ON 
`cart`.`id` = `products->products_carts`.`cartId` WHERE `cart`.`id` = 1;
```

the ouput i am getting:

```
{
    "cart": {
        "id": 1,
        "products": [
            {
                "id": 1,
                "products_carts": { // I DONT WANT THIS TO BE SHOWN !!!
                    "createdAt": "2022-12-25T13:42:16.000Z",
                    "updatedAt": "2022-12-25T13:42:16.000Z",
                    "cartId": 1,
                    "productId": 1
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

the relation between them is ..

```
Cart.belongsToMany(Product, { through: PC });
Product.belongsToMany(Cart, { through: PC });
User.hasOne(Cart);
Cart.belongsTo(User);
```

PC stands for `products_carts`

Comment: did you try to add `through: { attributes: [] }` in `include` option?

Answer (score 0):

through: { attributes: [] } worked for me